# Use MetroMessageBox in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-metro, messagebox

I'm making a GUI for a PowerShell script and want to display a `MetroMessageBox` using `MetroFramework`, it only needs to have a message and the OK button for dismissal.

Searching online everything I found was for VB.Net and C#. I've looked on how to run VB.Net and C# code within PS, tried it with no luck.

Looking at the `MessageBox` class in the `System.Windows` code

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Hello')
```

I've tried, with no luck.

```
[MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox]::Show('Hello')
```

How can I use `MetroMessageBox` in PowerShell?

Comment: Looking like you will need to add the libraries with `Add-Type` Then you should be able to use the method which should look something like this: `[MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox]::Show(this, "Your message here.","Title Here",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Hand)`

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this

```
[MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox]::Show($mainForm,"Your message here.","Title Here","OK","Info","211")
```

Did not need to use Add-Type or any other things